My answer was deleted (by '3 users vote' ) and isn't off topic

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: What is the relationship between iostream and namespace std?
My answer was deleted (by '3 users vote' ) and isn't off-topic nor match criteria, according to what is clearly explained in How does deleting work? (on 'Stack Exchange' - Meta).
They could down vote it.
If someone can interest about this issue and, eventually, vote to undelete my post, it will be very appreciated.
Also, I'm interested in the eventual, reasons for the deletion of my post and, eventually, if someone could explain them to me, please.
My deleted answer:




I am not an SME but from the little I do know your answer was incorrect in the 2nd paragraph and didn't actually explain anything relevant to the question in the 1st paragraph (which was also quite vague). Three trusted users decided that the answer wasn't very useful (given inaccuracy among other reasons) and decided to vote to delete it. Also the question already has some suitable answers you might want to refrain from adding a new one unless your answer adds something new / useful.

I can't say much about the content of your answer, as I do not know C++. What I can say is that it is very hard to read. It might help you in the future, if you take a moment and try to formulate correct and full English sentences.

You can see the guidance given to users who are allowed to delete answers here.

I would suggest that the answer meets these criteria for deletion: (1) it is not an answer: it seems to comment on namespace but does not address the OP's question (2) It adds no value to the site, because the commentary is irrelevant to the question and too confusing written to be useful even as commentary.

Could you share with us the information sources used to write your answer?

Yeah I do know some C++... and I can't read that answer, it is unintelligible to me. That's a brain dump, not a quality answer written to transfer knowledge and understanding. Still I would have downvoted myself, low quality is not a flagging reason.

@Gimby the answer probably wasn't flagged, users with 20k+ rep can cast delete votes on answers that have a negative score which is what happened here.

Sorry for my "slang" but is Simplified, is true that is better 'main c++ library' (I've not used "... "), I mean that it must be used (I avoided to mention others that can be used instead I only added this->(...) again to simplify... I tried a "simple" answer based on various aspects of the questions (may the author be very new to coding?), I looked that wasn't my point of view... (is so redundant !??)

In first, my answer is focused on using namespace std (and also the question, I think, by a point of view). Abdul Aziz Barkat is not a reason for a deletion is specified in the post of meta Stack Exchange I mentioned, the I tried to figure what is in mind of who made the question.

Abdul Aziz Barkat is a 3 vote deletion (there are the 3 voters), I think...

@Gimby I would be so pleased to see a similar thing written by u... (brain dump !!??)

@snakecharmerb I can't write only 'no comment', Why my post conflict with "KBs", and you think that I only see as a point of view answered by my post that explain something also for noobs that had found the informIT website?

there are no valid reason for a 'delete'.

Why did you even feel that question needed yet another answer to what already exists in there and is upvoted and accepted? What you posted what mostly incoherent. Any mention of using namespace std; that's not negative is already a huge red flag. That post was a mistake. We all make those. IMHO you should be glad it was deleted, unless you really wanted to collect some more downvotes. Let it go.

@Dan Mašek from original question: "had to add using namespace std; to my code!"

@Dan Mašek then, before "Let it Go", I try to collect more downvotes... and/or upvotes...

I don't think that one was salvageable, you've been done a favour. I've made similar mistakes when I started too. Hence, the "let it go", don't worry about it. Making useful contributions to SO is very difficult.

@Dan Mašek So they can delete almost all the posts... (hence is menacing...? I lost the chance to Let it Go?). Then a favor? They should had let it go... in my opinion. It's a kinda steal of interlocutory post?

@Dan Mašek anyway I appreciate very much your hints.

The main problem, I see, is communication. Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395985/if-i-let-chatgpt-improve-a-post-of-mine-linguistically-does-that-count-as-ai-g I think in your case it would not be a bad idea to ask ChatGPT to proofread your answer (but without the code/solution) and suggest how to improve its legibility.

@Mari-LouA do note that if they use generative AI to reword their answer that is not allowed by the ban (we simply cannot distinguish if someone used it "just for rewording"). It would be better to recommend solutions that don't use generative AI.

@AbdulAzizBarkat on the other hand you wouldn't have users telling the OP they don't understand the answer. Please note, I clearly stated that the "code/solution" should not be proofread that should only be modified by the user. Rewording a text to make its meaning clearer can only be achieved by competent speakers. I see no one offering to help, so let him use GenAI to save his answer.

@AbdulAzizBarkat  There is Deepl which is a very good online translator tool, pvt-Tron  can write their answer in their mother tongue and  get it to translate it into English. They must be able to write competently in their first language though, and make sure they do not misspell anything. Deepl does not correct grammar or vocabulary errors if there are present in the original text. Does Deepl also count as GenAI?  Then SO will have to ban spellcheckers in browsers as well.

@Mari-LouA the code / solution not being proofread by gen AI is not really the point. The main way the community detects such answer is obviously from the text (non-code) content of the post. Which is the reason the ban extends to that usage as well (otherwise everyone could use that as an excuse). I do understand you mean well there but this advice can cause OP to get suspended if they follow through with it.

@Mari-LouA translation tools are different from generative AI and the ban doesn't extend to those. Unless of course someone is using Gen AI as a translation tool.

@Mari-LouA With all due respect, wouldn't it be more productive to suggest that the user take an English course rather than waste their own time and that of their colleagues answering technical questions in a language they don't know, aided by GPT?

The user profile says they are from Italy. Problem solved, in future they should use Deepl. @AugustoVasques   Really, the user needs someone to suggest they should study English?  For how many months or years before the community will actually consider an answer worthy of the community. Must they take a certification to validate their level. What B2 level? That's roughly equivalent to a 5.5. or 6.0 in IELTS

@Zoe The fact I said, and repeated that the answer/code/solution should only be modified by the user means I do know what genAI does. And I use it to proofread students' essays, which it does very quickly. I use it as a tool, for my specific needs. I certainly do not use ChatGPT 3.5/4 or Gemini etc. to rewrite students' essays. You can instruct the programme to only identify errors in vocabulary, spelling, punctuation and grammar. EDIT The mod deleted their comment before I posted my reply.

@Mari-LouA, The guy can't communicate and got upset if questioned about sources.   Probably he already using a AI translation tool, I'm talking about minimum ability to perform a task.

@Augusto Vasques But, what you understand reading my answer?

@Mari-Lou A ...never heard about b1/b2... etc. ? I got also English I c/o Universitiy of Economy in PV-Ita... and I'm reading English from I was 12 years old... I don't use gtp nor translator, sometimes, I look for a word on a .dic site (what is a .dic? : is dictionary files ext.). I can try to carefully examine both your posts and those belong to Abdul Aziz Barkat... Please try to do it each-other (looking also at word that aren't not commonly used, are never used at all...).
(P.S. ndr answering @AugustoVasques 'they' "are" 'me' (cfr. the user needs)? Or the Italians!??)

@Mari-LouA 4 Sources using namespace std has the only purpose of allow the coder to omit the prefix std:: where would be necessary. namespace is more complex but by itself not so much (mainly it define a scope{ } to create an isolated space in main code), but is not a topic of my answer. (Need really sources? in that case can buy G4G premium [I'm subscribed]).

You're translating word for word Italian to English. This isn't how English is supposed to be spoken. Besides, I know nothing about coding, programming and their languages, so whatever you are telling me is gobbledegook and it would be exactly the same if you were speaking to me in Italian.

@Mari-Lou A Even if you come from Proficiency you may fail, I object radically your opinion about my English syntax (out of this: who used gobbledegook last time?), then an English or a bilingual with very high Proficiency Degree may say that always but I think that this isn't stackOver.Eng. Aren't You putting on the table too much aren't you? I red all of your comments...

People have repeatedly told you in the comments and in answers  that your answer was difficult to understand With respect, your writing style and English usage are quite difficult to read. It's not just the syntax, it's whether it sounds idiomatic and natural : "Then an English … with a very Proficiency Degree may say that always”, it's also the grammar: "Aren't You putting on the table too much aren't you?", and the spelling: "I red"  Ignore their observations at your own peril, but I suggest you use Deepl before posting future answers, it's a very good online translator tool.

@Mari-LouA: It ought to be stressed that with any of these automatic translators you need sufficient competence in the target language to be able to check their outputs. I got Deepl to translate one of my answers &, while the result was impressive in some ways, it still managed to make a nonsense of it. Technical writing is especially vulnerable to mistranslation (even human translators need some background in the subject matter to do a good job).

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica  The OP's English only needs to make sense and be comprehensible to the majority of Anglo-speakers. It doesn't have to be flawless, but if their answer doesn't make sense in their native tongue there's no translation programme on earth that can fix that.

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica  For example, the OP writes: 1. I got also English I c/o Universitiy of Economy  = I also passed an English exam [what type of exam is unclear] at the university of Pavia in Economics (probably equivalent to English level B1)  2. and I'm reading English from I was 12 years old. I've been studying English since I was 12 years old.  There are many simple mistakes in basic English grammar that an online translator tool would have taken care of.

@Marie-Lou: A translation needn't be flawless, but it does need to be faithful; else there's no point to it. The purported translation Deepl gave me was good enough English but statistical nonsense, which doesn't suffice for a Statistics Q&A site. All I'm saying is that if you don't know enough English to be able to judge the fidelity of a translation from your native language (perhaps after a little research), you oughtn't to put your faith in an automatic translator.

@Marie-Lou Scortchi-ReinstateMonica You say that is better to write the post in own language (in a WP) and then translate to English? Then I use Firefox so I succeed to Think in English (like in the famous film). You both styled, but 1 thing is speak about English (I would very pleased to read about English by You both, or chat), an other one is about C++(see Farlight 84 the Sniper Girl frequent comment in game "friends, this is what I was talking about" ). Also Reverso is good.

@Marie-Lou Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Inglese I = English B1 (4.5-5.0). Have You a nice online website to get online the b1/b2 cert?


I'm interested in the eventual, reasons for the deletion of my post and, eventually, if someone could explain them to me, please.

First reason for being deleted (as I am one of the user that voted to delete it) is that the answer is completely wrong. For one, you say and I quote;

Mainly <iostream> is C++ standard library, instead namespace is an advanced command (cpp)

The above statement in your answer is wrong as <iostream> is not the C++ standard library and namespace is not a "command".
Additionally, the deleted answer talks about initialized and formatting but it is not clear what they mean by that.
Also, the statement:

 must be included always[...]) to use new and 'special' commands, in ex. using namespace std need  .

is wrong and doesn't make sense.

In my opinion, the answer is also unreadable (in addition to being wrong).

"<iostream> is not c++ standard library" Given the poor English, the author was probably trying to say that <iostream> is part of the C++ standard library.

@E_net4 Note also that their old question among others, seems to suggest that they do know enough english. For example, in the linked post, OP has used words like "equipped". So I don't think they meant " is part of the C++ standard library"

Also, for argument's sake, if we make very generous inferences about what was meant rather than what is actually written then the answer merely duplicates information in existing answers and thus adds no value.

But, please Pres. try to be flexible... (have any example? or you pasted chosen a side?) then, you and your friends loose your time for an evaluation like this above and that made deleted my post?

Sorry for my "slang" but is Simplified, but E_net4 I think You right is better 'main c++ library' (I've not used "... ") user12002570 is also right I mean that it must be used (I avoided to mention others that can be used instead I only added this->(...) again to simplify... I tried a "simple" answer based on various aspects of the questions (may the author be very new to coding?), I looked that wasn't my point of view... (is so redundant !??).

@user12002570 what is wrong in my answer?

there are no valid reason for a 'delete'.

@pvt-Tron What do you mean "what is wrong in my answer?" user12002570 has very clearly explained what is wrong with your answer. I understand that you disagree with their explanation, but that doesn't mean that one wasn't provided.

@F1Krazy from original question: "had to add using namespace std; to my code!",
and none of the reasons he answered is valid for a deletion (is expressed explained here).

I have no idea what you mean by that.

@pvt-Tron "namespace is not a "command" ? why?..." Because there is no such thing as a command in c++ standard. Maybe you meant keyword. But that is entirely different. And it is important to use correct terminology especially in a language like c++. Inventing new terms is not recommended(as it can confuse people/readers as done in your deleted answer).

user12002570 echo off and append are  commands and  expressions almost like namespace (if you like, keywords ** too) or ios::app... then it not confuse instead may be more familiar for the newbies. Focus that the best term is expression... and you ignore the directive for answer deletion... (you find it in my post, there is also popup description on mouse-over)

@pvt-Tron: I cannot quite understand your comment, though it's clear you disagree. My point is that there are already a number of answers; what new information or insight does your answer bring? We don't need to duplicate other answers.

@President James K. Polk I wrote above:
But, please Pres. try to be flexible... (have any example? or you pasted chosen a side?) then, you and your friends loose your time for an evaluation like this above and that made deleted my post?

@pvt-Tron Repeating the same phrasing that someone has already stated they don't understand is not helpful.

I'm reading this answer as, roughly (correcting terminology issues and typos, but trying to preserve meaning):

<iostream> is part of the C++ standard library. namespace is an advanced keyword used as boilerplate setup in almost all C++ code to simplify writing the code. For now, try to see using namespace std1  like int main; essentially, as boilerplate to copy-paste into a new file. Normally, this is explained after functions are already learned.
It is more important to concern yourself with the #include<...> statements.  You will need more than one #include (<iostream> must always be included) to use new and 'special' commands; for example, using namespace std needs <iostream>.2

This is essentially saying to ignore using namespace and just copy-paste it in.  The question is what it does; telling someone to ignore it does not answer that question.  While we allow frame challenges in answers, this answer is really not challenging the framing, but instead avoiding the question entirely.  And assuming the claim is that "almost all c++ codes" use using namespace std, it's also wrong (this is not the only incorrect statement).  While just being wrong is usually not a reason to delete an answer, that is not the only one of several issues here.
With respect, your writing style and English usage are quite difficult to read.  I did my best to understand it, already knowing the correct answer to the question, and I was still unable to figure out what some of it means after looking at it for quite a while.  Please consider using one of the many free grammar-checking tools available online, as well as carefully checking the technical parts for correctness (you wrote "unsing" instead of "using" both times you posted this answer, for example).

1 It is unclear to me whether the original answer was intended to refer to using namespace std specifically, or using namespace generally.  Given the context of the question, I've assumed the former.
2 I cannot figure out what this sentence is trying to say.  It appears to claim that multiple includes will be needed, but then gives the example of <iostream> again.  It also appears to claim that <iostream> must be included to use using namespace std, which is wrong.

He ask why he should add using namespace std to his code.(!)

2 according to me who ask seams a newbie (totally) so I thought an answer based on this thesis, your correction are like the typical elephant running in crystal's shop, and is all what I has avoided to brutally express, then multiple include are not important atm they will be when he will use expressions that need the inclusion of other library (I intentionally omitted this term) I say that using namespace std is almost necessary and need <iostream> that is absolutely necessary(...). Then cook a boilerplate of coffee for u a ur 4cats.

"cook a boilerplate of coffee for u a ur 4cats" - is that supposed to be some sort of insult?

Perhaps in the user's writing style "cook a boilerplate of coffee for u a ur 4cats." means a "thank you for the answer".

" While just being wrong is usually not a reason to delete an answer, that is not the only one of several issues here" - yeah... I can agree with that actually. Practically the answer is just not English but rather some kind of fever dream version of it. So I guess that kind of makes the answer go beyond the "use your downvotes, not your nukes". This time.
